# Perforce version server won't start because of exceeded user count limit and version mismatch

Tags: server, upgrade, perforce, licensing

I discovered today that my Perforce server was not accessible and, after a lot of digging around, I think the server must have automatically upgraded the p4 server programs.  Right now p4d isn't running so I can't do anything with it.

This server was setup for a team of University students when they provided a free 20 user license.  It seems they've dropped that option, and I don't see any option to revert back to a version that is under that license.  I can live with the new 5 user limit if need be, but only if I can get past the situation that I find myself in.

Below are the commands and responses that have me in a bind.  As you see, I'm in a circular problem.  I can't run p4d because the license count is exceeded.  I can't run the server in maintenance mode bacause the db needs to be upgraded, and I can't run the upgrade because I don't have enough licenses.

My first preference would be to downgrade to the version that was running just fine.  If that's not possible, then deleting some users so I can at least get things working would also be acceptable.

The server is running Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Thanks for any help.

```
root@ubuntu14-server:/opt/perforce/servers/p4test# p4d
Perforce server error:
        Warning! You have exceeded the usage limits of Perforce Helix. Version 16.1 allows up to five users without commercial licenses. You may continue your current usage with previous versions of our software.

        Try deleting old users with 'user -d'.
        License count: 11 users used of 5 licensed.

        For additional licenses, contact Perforce Sales at sales@perforce.com.
root@ubuntu14-server:/opt/perforce/servers/p4test# p4d -n
Perforce server error:
        Database is at old upgrade level 23.  Use 'p4d -r /opt/perforce/servers/p4test -xu' to upgrade to level 25.
root@ubuntu14-server:/opt/perforce/servers/p4test# p4d -r /opt/perforce/servers/p4test -xu
Perforce server error:
        Warning! You have exceeded the usage limits of Perforce Helix. Version 16.1 allows up to five users without commercial licenses. You may continue your current usage with previous versions of our software.

        Try deleting old users with 'user -d'.
        License count: 11 users used of 5 licensed.

        For additional licenses, contact Perforce Sales at sales@perforce.com.
```

/var/log/dpkg.log from two weeks ago shows the update happening:

```
2016-10-11 20:41:01 upgrade perforce-p4dctl:amd64 2015.1-1227227~trusty 2015.2-1443805~trusty
2016-10-11 20:41:01 status half-configured perforce-p4dctl:amd64 2015.1-1227227~trusty
2016-10-11 20:41:04 status unpacked perforce-p4dctl:amd64 2015.1-1227227~trusty
2016-10-11 20:41:04 status half-installed perforce-p4dctl:amd64 2015.1-1227227~trusty
2016-10-11 20:41:04 status half-installed perforce-p4dctl:amd64 2015.1-1227227~trusty
2016-10-11 20:41:05 status unpacked perforce-p4dctl:amd64 2015.2-1443805~trusty
2016-10-11 20:41:05 status unpacked perforce-p4dctl:amd64 2015.2-1443805~trusty
2016-10-11 20:41:06 install helix-p4dctl:amd64 <none> 2016.1-1446835~trusty
2016-10-11 20:41:06 status half-installed helix-p4dctl:amd64 2016.1-1446835~trusty
2016-10-11 20:41:07 status triggers-pending ureadahead:amd64 0.100.0-16
2016-10-11 20:41:07 status half-installed helix-p4dctl:amd64 2016.1-1446835~trusty
2016-10-11 20:41:08 status unpacked helix-p4dctl:amd64 2016.1-1446835~trusty
2016-10-11 20:41:08 status unpacked helix-p4dctl:amd64 2016.1-1446835~trusty
```

Comment: I don't believe the Perforce server itself ever automatically upgrades itself, so some sysadmin on your machine must have initiated an upgrade of the Perforce server package. Try looking in your server logs to see if you can figure out what the old server version was. "upgrade level 23" could be anything between 2012.1 and 2015.1, so you need to figure out the *exact* version.

Comment: Looks like the automatic package updater did it.  This is from dpkg.log from two weeks ago. Added info to original post.

Comment: Darn auto-updaters. :( If you can figure out the *precise* version that you were running before, I believe you should be able to put that binary back in place and get your server up again, at least long enough to recover your data. That *precise* version information can be recovered from your server's log file or journal file from when it was last running, which should be in simple text files in /opt/perforce, in a directory next to a bunch of files named 'db.*.'

Comment: Any idea where to get the binaries from?  I've scoured the server for copies of p4d and the only one that I can find is the new one.  On the Perforce web site, it doesn't seeme there is any way of recovering old versions.  Best I can see is the latest patched release of the different versions, but not the previous ones.

Comment: If they're not on perforce.com, that might be a challenge. Perhaps on archive.org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem

If you have updated via package manager:

Centos

```
yum downgrade helix
```

Ubuntu

```
apt-get install «pkg»=«version»
```

Manually

```
http://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/
```

The 16.1 version is the one that changes the limit from 20 to 5.

The catch is that even with the downgrade to version 2015.2, it keeps not starting complaining about the 5 user licence. (duh?)

But if you run **p4 -n** you will be able to login, acess the administration and delete some users to move on (to gitlab i hope, lol)

Comment: I think it's `p4d -n`, not `p4 -n`; good idea to use that to be able to delete your excess users to get back operational again.

Comment: This stuff is seriously difficult to work with.  It's a shame it's the only decent VC system that integrates properly with UE4.

Had to get 2015.1 to be able to run the p4 -n command because the DB was an older version, and I couldn't upgrade until I'd solved the user count issue.

The second I got the user count down, I was immediately met with an error about having too many clients!

After more searching, these were the commands I then used to get past that (for the benefit of others that find themselves in this spot):

> p4 login
> p4 clients
> p4 client -f -d [client name]